# How to set IsSelected property for some ListBox entries?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox of PerformanceCounter objects (my ListBox is bound to ObservableCollection of Performanceounter objects).
Now, I need to be able to elect some of the entries in this ListBox from code-behind. The problem is, that when i try to iterate through ListBox entries:

```
        foreach (var item in currentListBox.Items)
        {
            ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)item;
            listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
```

I get an Exception: `InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.).`

In the code above I try to select all entries in my ListBox, just as an example.
How can I properly set IsSelected property for the chosen entries?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the SelectedItems property:

```
foreach (var item in currentListBox.Items)
{
    currentListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why didn't I think about it?